Run Asp.net 8.0 Background job without Time Cancelation Exceptions
Hi I am implementing background job which will run every 5 sec.
This job will send message to client(1 lack) using SignalR.
I am saving this signalR connection Id in db when client connect with signalR server. So background job will read the connection details and calling web api to process message in runtime and send the message to client.
before calling the API job will call Couchbase database to get some data and pass the data into API
Some time while calling database we are getting Task Cancelation exception.
How we make sure all jobs are running without any exceptions.

Can you show the code you are using and show the exceptions you are getting?  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Couchbase calls will cancel operations that exceed the specified timeout.
